# $_GET All the transmitted data

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have a.php file that send some elements data to b.php with GET method.
I b.php we don`t know id of elements in a.php file.
But we need access them.
Are there any way to read all submited data in b.php?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit more. So you have GET data and you want to find out what it contains?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump ($_GET); perhaps your array is empty?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) structure:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    // Do something
}
```

`$_GET` is a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php). [Here is the doc about it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Like for all variables, [you can dump its content and structured information about it to the output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) with the `var_dump()` function. This will help you to understand how it work.

`$_GET` only returns parameters passed by HTTP GET. It's commonly the part after the question mark in the URI, e.g. `?key1=value1&key2=value2`

You can also use `$_REQUEST` ([documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)) to retrieve all the values passed in the request by GET, POST, and COOKIE.

Some people think using `$_REQUEST` is unsafe, but IMHO, check the HTTP method have a very poor interest (well, not interest at all), because it depend of the user. And the user can trick this very easily.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following to list all arguments.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To access all the data in the $_GET global array, you can do something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
   echo "$key: $value";
```

Comment: @ComFreek That's good for debugging purposes, but I assume the OP wants to actually use the data in his app.

Comment: Because var_dump() only outputs the structure. Using foreach() you can do whatever you want.